# updating facebook sdk from v3 to v4 Android

Tags: android, facebook

I have a problem figuring out what methods or classes to use when implementing facebook SDK v4 in my codes, when they originally were written for v3. I have searched through Facebook's Developers page and found some answers, but I still have som issues. Here are my codes:

Session is removed in v4 so I don't know what to replace it with in this sample:

```
    // Fetch Facebook user info if the session is active
    Session session = ParseFacebookUtils.getSession();
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        makeMeRequest();
    }
```

I also gets an error in AUTHENTICATION_RETRY and AUTHENTICATION_REOPEN_SESSION here:

```
                        // handle errors accessing data from facebook
                    } else if (response.getError() != null) {
                        if ((response.getError().getCategory() == FacebookRequestError.Category.AUTHENTICATION_RETRY)
                                || (response.getError().getCategory() == FacebookRequestError.Category.AUTHENTICATION_REOPEN_SESSION)) {
                            Log.i(AnypicApplication.TAG,
                                    "The facebook session was invalidated.");
                            onLogoutButtonClicked();
                        } else {
                            Log.i(AnypicApplication.TAG,
                                    "Some other error: "
                                            + response.getError()
                                                    .getErrorMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    request.executeAsync();
```

And the same here:

```
                        // handle errors from facebook
                    } else if (response.getError() != null) {
                        if ((response.getError().getCategory() == FacebookRequestError.Category.AUTHENTICATION_RETRY)
                                || (response.getError().getCategory() == FacebookRequestError.Category.AUTHENTICATION_REOPEN_SESSION)) {
                            Log.i(AnypicApplication.TAG,
                                    "The facebook session was invalidated.");
                            onLogoutButtonClicked();
                        } else {
                            Log.i(AnypicApplication.TAG,
                                    "Some other error: "
                                            + response.getError()
                                                    .getErrorMessage());
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Here GraphUserListCallback and GraphUser shows up as red:

```
private void autoFollowFacebookFriendsRequest(){
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphUserListCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> friendList, GraphResponse response) {
                    if(friendList != null){
                        List<String> ids = toIdsList(friendList);
```

and here GraphUser and getId

```
private List<String> toIdsList(List<GraphUser> fbUsers){
    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(GraphUser user : fbUsers){
        ids.add(user.getId());
    }
    return ids;
}
```

And the last one: closeAndClearTokenInformation

```
private void onLogoutButtonClicked() {
    // close this user's session
    ParseFacebookUtils.getSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
```

Here is the whole class:

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.FacebookRequestError;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class HomeListActivity extends ListActivity {

private HomeViewAdapter mHomeViewAdapter;
private UserViewAdapter mUserViewAdapter;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_list);
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // Photo clicked == parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Item clicked: " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).getClass().getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Subclass of ParseQueryAdapter
    mHomeViewAdapter = new HomeViewAdapter(this);
    mUserViewAdapter = new UserViewAdapter(this);

    // Default view
    setListAdapter(mHomeViewAdapter);

    // Fetch Facebook user info if the session is active
    Session session = ParseFacebookUtils.getSession();
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        makeMeRequest();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //Log.i(AnypicApplication.TAG, "Entered HomeListActivity onResume()");

    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        // Check if the user is currently logged
        // and show any cached content

    } else {
        // If the user is not logged in, go to the
        // activity showing the login view.
        startLoginActivity();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

/*
 * Posting pictures and refreshing the list will be controlled from the Action
 * Bar.
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.action_refresh: {
        updateHomeList();
        break;
    }

    case R.id.action_person: {
        showUser();
        break;
    }

    case R.id.action_new: {
        newPhoto();
        break;
    }

    case R.id.logout: {
        onLogoutButtonClicked();
        break;
    }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void updateHomeList() {
    mHomeViewAdapter.loadObjects();
    setListAdapter(mHomeViewAdapter);
}

private void showUser() {
    mUserViewAdapter.loadObjects();
    setListAdapter(mUserViewAdapter);
}

private void newPhoto() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NewPhotoActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // If a new post has been added, update
        // the list of posts
        updateHomeList();
    }
}

/**
 * Requesting and setting user data. Essentially, this is the User constructor
 */
private void makeMeRequest() {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        // get the relevant data using the GraphAPI
                        // and store them as fields in our ParseUser

                        /*
                         * User Model
                         * 
                         * displayName : String
                         * email : string
                         * profilePictureMedium : File
                         * profilePictureSmall : File
                         * facebookId : String
                         * facebookFriends : Array
                         * channel : String
                         * userAlreadyAutoFollowedFacebookFriends : boolean
                         */
                        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser
                                .getCurrentUser();
                        currentUser.put("facebookId", user.optString("facebookId"));
                        currentUser.put("displayName", user.optString("displayName"));
                        currentUser.saveInBackground();

                        // Make another facebook request to auto follow all of
                        // the current user's facebook friends who are using Anypic
                        if( currentUser.get("userAlreadyAutoFollowedFacebookFriends")!=null &&
                                ((Boolean) currentUser.get("userAlreadyAutoFollowedFacebookFriends")) ){
                            // do nothing
                            Log.i(AnypicApplication.TAG, "Already followed facebook friends");
                        } else{
                            autoFollowFacebookFriendsRequest(); 
                        }
                        // Associate the device with a user
                        ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
                        installation.put("user", currentUser);
                        installation.saveInBackground();

                        // handle errors accessing data from facebook
                    } else if (response.getError() != null) {
                        if ((response.getError().getCategory() == FacebookRequestError.Category.AUTHENTICATION_RETRY)
                                || (response.getError().getCategory() == FacebookRequestError.Category.AUTHENTICATION_REOPEN_SESSION)) {
                            Log.i(AnypicApplication.TAG,
                                    "The facebook session was invalidated.");
                            onLogoutButtonClicked();
                        } else {
                            Log.i(AnypicApplication.TAG,
                                    "Some other error: "
                                            + response.getError()
                                                    .getErrorMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    request.executeAsync();

}

/**
 * This function performs a request to the Facebook Graph API, which 
 * finds all the friends of the current ParseUser and checks if any 
 * of them currently use Anypic. If so, then it automatically follows 
 * those friends on Anypic, by creating new Activity relationships. 
 */
private void autoFollowFacebookFriendsRequest(){
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphUserListCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> friendList, GraphResponse response) {
                    if(friendList != null){
                        List<String> ids = toIdsList(friendList);

                        // Select * From Users Where User.facebookID is contained in 
                        // the list of IDs of users returned from the GraphApi
                        ParseQuery<ParseUser> friendsQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
                        friendsQuery.whereContainedIn("facebookId", ids);
                        friendsQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                                if(e == null && objects!=null){
                                    // friendsQuery successful, follow these users
                                    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                                    for(ParseUser friend : objects){
                                        com.parse.starter.Activity followActivity = new com.parse.starter.Activity();
                                        followActivity.setFromUser(currentUser);
                                        followActivity.setToUser(friend);
                                        followActivity.setType("follow");
                                        followActivity.saveEventually();
                                    }
                                    currentUser.put("userAlreadyAutoFollowedFacebookFriends", true);
                                    currentUser.saveInBackground();
                                } else {
                                    // friendsQuery failed
                                    Log.i(AnypicApplication.TAG, "Query to find facebook friends in Parse failed");
                                }
                            }
                        }); // end findInBackground()


                        // handle errors from facebook
                    } else if (response.getError() != null) {
                        if ((response.getError().getCategory() == FacebookRequestError.Category.AUTHENTICATION_RETRY)
                                || (response.getError().getCategory() == FacebookRequestError.Category.AUTHENTICATION_REOPEN_SESSION)) {
                            Log.i(AnypicApplication.TAG,
                                    "The facebook session was invalidated.");
                            onLogoutButtonClicked();
                        } else {
                            Log.i(AnypicApplication.TAG,
                                    "Some other error: "
                                            + response.getError()
                                                    .getErrorMessage());
                        }
                    }

                }
            });// end GraphUserListCallback
    request.executeAsync();     
}

// Take a list of Facebook GraphUsers and return a list of their IDs
private List<String> toIdsList(List<GraphUser> fbUsers){
    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(GraphUser user : fbUsers){
        ids.add(user.getId());
    }
    return ids;
}

private void onLogoutButtonClicked() {
    // close this user's session
    ParseFacebookUtils.getSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    // Log the user out
    ParseUser.logOut();
    // Go to the login view
    startLoginActivity();
}

private void startLoginActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has an upgrade guide here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x

If you scroll all the way to the bottom you will see an upgrade guide for 3.x to 4.x